# JProfiler7: Set Up Local Proxy

Tags: java, profiling, weblogic, jprofiler

Good time!

I need to integrate JProfile7 and Weblogic 11g. I have done all the steps are described for this and nearly everithing is ok except the following thing.

My application connects to the remote data base and there is a proxy server that I need to use to communicate to the world outside the company.

As far as JProfiler rewrites the Weblogic's start script to use its agent, there should be a way to tell it to use the proxy, but I can't find how do this.

Could somebody, please, suggest, how to do this?

*EDIT:*
I've tried to use the 
`-Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=12.121.12.12  -Dhttps.proxyPort=1212` java options, but the problem remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't know the main cause of the problem, but to resolve the issue I've done the following:

1. created a new file: profiledStartScript.bat outside the weblogic server's bin directory.
2. added the following lines:

   set DOMAIN_HOME=C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/myDomain

   set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849

   call "%DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\startWebLogic.cmd"

and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your application and the jProfiler are running **within the same network** without any proxy restrictions, you should be fine. It is the application, not jProfiler, who communicates with the proxied DB node.

You should be able to start your application as is - if the app is using the current proxy, then the same app with the jProfiler settings will be also using that given proxy. There should not be any difference in the application behavior.

Also, you start the application VM, let it run for a while with the correct proxy and then attach the jProfiler to the application - thiw will not change the proxy settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is when I start the Weblogic server manually (with the original Weblogic start script), I can see the connection to the DB in the Proxifier, but when I do this (even manually) with the file, generated by the JProfiler, I couldn't see it. And the Proxifier is set up to listen to any application on my machine, so maybe JProfiler tries to connect to the outside world with some special method?